# C++ create executable file and run it on runtime

Tags: c++, runtime, executable

i have a broad question.

In Java, we can do so by using JarOututStream to create a jar file and execute it, but what about C++? Is there a way to create an executable file on runtime and run it? I have tried searching but to no avail, some advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to execute a compiler to create an executable, just like you do yourself.

Comment: What OS are you using and which compiler is installed?

Comment: You can. Just compile it.

Comment: I am running Windows, is there an API which can be called to invoke the compiler to create an executable file (E.g a hello world program) during runtime? Or should i rephrase it, is there anything somewhat similar to JarOutputStream? Sorry I am a C++ beginner and i tried looking up online, but to no avail.
P.S: Using Microsoft Visual C++